# How do i create images with specified resolution?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, resolution

I want to create an image with resolution of 56 pixels/diameter (with varying diameters of say: 50, 100, and 150 pixels), by first specifying its height and width and then using the meshgrid function to digitize the image (see example code below). Secondly, how do i increase the resolution by a factor of 2 (say: 112, and 224 pixels/diameter)?

Example:

```
RowSize = 400;
ColSize = 400;

[gridRow, gridCol] = meshgrid(1:RowSize, 1:ColSize);

%specify the diameter
d = 100;

% create the image
I       = (gridRow - 200).^2 + (gridCol - 200).^2 <= (d/2).^2;
figure, imshow(I, []);
```

The main issue I will think is how to determine the Row and Col sizes such that I have the desired resolutions.

Please any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
%specify the diameter
d = 100;

RowSize = d;
ColSize = d;

%Subtract 0.5 to get the center correclty
[gridRow, gridCol] = meshgrid((1:RowSize)-0.5, (1:ColSize)-0.5);

% create the image
I = (gridRow - d/2).^2 + (gridCol - d/2).^2 <= (d/2).^2;
figure, imshow(I, []);
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rotem. It works this way, but then i actually want to create the image from scratch by specifying the height and width. I have edited the question accordingly. Please do take a look. Thanks for your time!.

Comment: Now I really got lost... the resolution of both `gridRow` and `gridCol` is `RowSize x ColSize`. How do you create an image from `gridRow` and `gridCol` ?

Comment: Please see the remaining codes here:  `centerY  = RowSizeY/2;
centerX  = ColSizeX/2;
diameter = 100;

Img       = (gridRow - centerY).^2 + (gridCol - centerX).^2 <= (diameter/2).^2;
figure, imshow(Img, [], 'InitialMagnification','fit')`.  The code creates a disc in the centre of the image (didn't add them cos i wasn't sure if you were going to need those). Let me know your thoughts please.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks @Rotem, we're almost getting there. Does the specified resolution of 56 pix/diameter not mean that there will be a total of 5600 pixels in the entire image for a diameter of 100 pixels?

Comment: No, 56 pix/diameter means 1 diameter is 56 pixels (like heart rate of 60 beats/min means 1 minute has 60 beats). 56 pix/diameter means the diameter of the circle is exactly 56 pixels. Because 1 diameter is bounded by squared image, the image size is 56x56 pixels.

Comment: In case you are convinced that you need to get `5600` pixels in the entire image, you can easily compute the width (number of columns) and height (number of rows) of the image: `width = sqrt(5600)`. place the width in `d` in the code I posted. You need to round the value first, but then there will be `round(sqrt(5600))^2` = `5625` pixels instead of `5600`. Decide how to deal with it.

Comment: I don't know if we have an English problem or a Math problem... Some references: [Diameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter). and [Does per (in math) mean division](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100311152131AAxkJz1). So division also means "per" and... `pixels/diameter` means: number of pixels **per** single diameter. (keep in mind that diameter is one dimensional unit - it's not the 2D area).

Comment: It's quite clear and i do get it now. What i did was to keep the image size constant and then i kept changing the resolution by changing the diameter from 56 to 112, 224 pixels, etc. Many thanks for your help. I do appreciate...